# Unable to access a webmethod from Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, ajax

I was creating a simple web method to access from Java script..But I am not able to

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(
        function test() {
            var x = PageMethods.MyMethod();
            alert(x.toString());
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind looks like this

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string MyMethod()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
```

Variable x is null. Iam not able to figure out what is is that Iam missing ?Any help ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where do you invoke function `test`?

Comment: @Chris .. its automatically invoked when document is ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to define a callback function which is invoked upon reciept of the response from the web method:

```
    $(document).ready(
    function test() {
        PageMethods.MyMethod(myMethodCallBackSuccess, myMethodCallBackFailed);
    })

    function myMethodCallBackSuccess(response) {
        alert(response);
    }

    function myMethodCallBackFailed(error) {
        alert(error.get_message());
    }
```

You may also pass arguments to the method however these must always come before the success and failure callbacks.

**Note**: you do not need to include the failed call back but it is available if required.